# If both violet light and red light was incident on the center of a semi circular block, and refracted, would they have the same refraction angle?

Tags: waves, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, dispersion

As the violet and red light have the same speed in air, with the incident angle being less than the critical, with the violet light and the red light coinciding on each other, (like on top of each other with the same angle), would the refraction angle be the same?? after leaving the block to air?

Comment: What do you think? What is your doubt?

Comment: is what im saying right?

Comment: What are you saying? Why do you doubt that your answer is correct? The purpose of this site is not to confirm whether you are right or wrong but to explain misunderstandings about physics. Questions should be useful for a range of users, not only yourself. Questions which ask for a Yes/No answer are not useful to others.

Comment: This answer will help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/541021/intuitive-explanation-for-why-blue-light-is-refracted-more-than-red-light/541031#541031